# Kill one particular session of running application C#

Tags: c#, process

I used to kill process like this :

```
Process []GetPArry = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process testProcess in GetPArry)  
        {
        string ProcessName = testProcess .ProcessName;              
        ProcessName  = ProcessName .ToLower();
        if (ProcessName.CompareTo("winword") == 0)
        testProcess.Kill();
        }
```

How can I kill only one session of the runnug process.
Is it possible?

Comment: Will you kill only the first process or a particular?

Comment: If you're killing off Microsoft Word, wouldn't a better idea be to hook into it using COM and ask it to quit nicely?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, Thanks, The Word is just for the example.

Comment: @EdiG., I would like to kill a particular instance of application.

Comment: then is the answer from Eldar Dordzhiev right. killed the first process with the name winword, then exit foreach loop

Comment: @EdiG., but eldar suggested to kill the first occurrence, not a particular. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right, here is my code:

```
Process []GetPArry = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process testProcess in GetPArry)  
{
    string ProcessName = testProcess.ProcessName;              
    ProcessName  = ProcessName.ToLower();
    if (ProcessName.CompareTo("winword") == 0)
    {
        testProcess.Kill();
        break;
    }
}
```

That will kill the first occurrence of the "winword" name.

But if you want to kill a particular instance of process, you need to obtain the PID first:

```
int pid = process.Id;
```

Then, you can easily kill it later:

```
Process []GetPArry = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process testProcess in GetPArry)  
{
    if (testProcess.Id == pid)
    {
        testProcess.Kill();
        break;
    }
}
```

And using Linq (because I really like it):

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(process => process.Id == pid).First().Kill();
```

Comment: Thanks, nice idea! and what about if I like to kill a particular instance?

Comment: Looks great! how can I get the ID of a process I've started programmatically, using `processInfo`?

Comment: @user3165438
var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
int pid = process.Id;

Comment: Thanks a lot! works like charm! Where can I get clear material about the linq issue? it sounds wonderful!

Comment: @user3165438 try this [step-by-step guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26743/Using-LINQ-to-Objects-in-C) on codeproject.com. Linq2Objects is really simple, you can deal with it for about a half hour :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with the SessionID

```
Process []GetPArry = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process testProcess in GetPArry)  
{
    string ProcessName = testProcess .ProcessName;              
    ProcessName  = ProcessName .ToLower();
    if (ProcessName.CompareTo("winword") == 0 && testProcess.SessionId == <SessionID>)
    {
        testProcess.Kill();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** get process-SessionID Process.Start returns a instance of Process

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(eaInstallationPath);
processInfo.Verb = "runas";
var myProcess = Process.Start(processInfo);
var mySessionID = myProcess.SessionId;
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the `<sessionID>` of a process that I started programmatically, using: `ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( eaInstallationPath);
processInfo.Verb = "runas";Process.Start(processInfo);`?